# How do I create two additional fields to a view based on output from two case statements

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I'm looking to create two additional fields with my query. Status (ACTIVE/INACTIVE) and REASON (BAU/EXPIRY) based on criteria. Currently it is one column, but I want to split it into two. Below is the code:

```
select first_name,last_name,end_date as "Contract end date",date_removed,
case  
when END_DATE > sysdate and DATE_REMOVED is null then 'ACTIVE'  
when END_DATE <= sysdate then 'INACTIVE - Contract Expired' 
when DATE_REMOVED is not null then 'INACTIVE - BAU'
end 
as status
from DEPARTMENTS d inner join employees e on e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
```

Want it to display

```
**STATUS**           **REASON**
ACTIVE           
ACTIVE           
INACTIVE         CONTRACT EXPIRY
INACTIVE         BAU
...               ...
```

Comment: What about a view instead?

Comment: brilliant, a view works perfectly. Just wanted to ask , do you know how to perform two case statements within a select?                                                         `code` select first_name,last_name,end_date,date_removed,
case  
when END_DATE > sysdate and DATE_REMOVED is null then 'ACTIVE'  
when END_DATE <= sysdate then 'INACTIVE - Contract Expired' 
when DATE_REMOVED is not null then 'INACTIVE - BAU'
end 
as status
from DEPARTMENTS d inner join employees e on e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID; `code`

Comment: I think the issue is because you are using SYSDATE reference and that is why you are getting pure function error. Give a static value instead of SYSDATE just to verify. As suggested if not possible you can create an use a view instead of a virtual column.

Comment: Maybe this: https://community.oracle.com/message/12370696#12370696 would help?

Comment: also you can alter table with char or varchar datatype and then update it.

Comment: thanks guys, I've followed the advice on creating a view. IT WORKS!! Horray. But I'm struggling to output the two calculated fields. Changed the question above, please have a go at this one.

Comment: your data is the status in case statement is inconsistent with what you want in ur output ..please adjust it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't normally answer my own question but below was what I was looking for

```
select first_name,last_name,end_date,date_removed,
case  
when END_DATE > sysdate and DATE_REMOVED is null then 'ACTIVE'  
when END_DATE <= sysdate then 'INACTIVE' 
end 
as status,
case  
when END_DATE <= sysdate then 'Contract Expired' 
when DATE_REMOVED is not null then 'BAU'
end 
as Reason
from DEPARTMENTS d inner join employees e on e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your sample...

```
select 
case when STATUS like '%ACTIVE%' is null then '' ,
   when STATUS like '%INACTIVE%'  and DATE_REMOVED is not null then 'BAU' 
   when STAUS like '%INACTIVE%' and END_DATE <= sysdate then 'Contract Expired'
end as REASON,
case when REASON IS NULL then 'ACTIVE'
    ESLE 'INACTIVE' end as STATUS

from (


select first_name,last_name,end_date as "Contract end date",date_removed,
case  
when END_DATE > sysdate and DATE_REMOVED is null then 'ACTIVE'  
when END_DATE <= sysdate then 'INACTIVE - Contract Expired' 
when DATE_REMOVED is not null then 'INACTIVE - BAU'
end 
as status
from DEPARTMENTS d inner join employees e on e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
     select a.*, substr(a.status,replace(instr(a.status,'-',1,1),0,LENGTH(a.status)) + 1) Reason from (select first_name,last_name,end_date as "Contract end date",date_removed,
     case  
     when END_DATE > sysdate and DATE_REMOVED is null then 'ACTIVE'  
     when END_DATE <= sysdate then 'INACTIVE - Contract Expired' 
     when DATE_REMOVED is not null then 'INACTIVE - BAU'
     end 
     as status
     from DEPARTMENTS d inner join employees e on e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID) a
```